# Percona XtraBackup - restoring a database backup into a MySQL server containing other databases

Tags: mysql, backup, percona

I am trying to migrate a large MySQL database using Percona XtraBackup (15 Gb).

The default innobackupex command to restore a backup requires moving or deleting the mysql datadir (/var/lib/mysql) :

```
mkdir /tmp/mysql
cd /var/lib/mysql/; mv * /tmp/mysql/
innobackupex --user=user --password=password --copy-back /data/backups/new_backup
```

The destination MySQL server is already containing several databases. Is there a way to restore the database alongside the existing databases (there will be no schema name conflict)?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed possible to restore a database using innobackup/xtrabackup to a running MySQL server.

Instead of using `--copy-back` use `--export` and [import each tablespace one at a time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-table-import.html). This is easily scripted.

`xtrabackup --export` will create .exp, .ibd, and .cfg files.

Answer (score 1):

No there's not a way to do what you want to do, I am afraid.

With that size of database, you could use mysqldump and then restore the data to where you want it to be https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html

There is an article here that you might find useful. It describes how you can split the data into several csv files, which is faster than using mysqldump to dump and restore to/from an SQL file, especially as you have the option then to use multiple threads.

https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/02/22/restore-mysql-logical-backup-maximum-speed/

As always when moving or changing data, do carry out tests before using the techniques on live data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I also started trying **mydumper** & **myloader**, it seems to significantly improve the dumping & restoring time [http://imagexmedia.com/blog/2014/11/speeding-your-mysql-dumprestores-mydumper](http://imagexmedia.com/blog/2014/11/speeding-your-mysql-dumprestores-mydumper)